# In Java is using the ellipsis to represent an optional parameter a good idea?

Tags: java, ellipsis

I'm wondering if using the ellipsis to represent an optional parameter is a good idea?

```
public void update(Object object, boolean... checkFirst)
{
    if (checkFirst[0])
    {
        ...
    } //if
} //update
```

I'm using code that connects to a DB table that doesn't have a primary key to allow multiple inserts (legacy code so please excuse any bad practice thoughts here).  So instead of using two methods (overloading) I was thinking I could possibly use the ellipsis to achieve the same effect.  But do you think this would be terrible practice?

Cheers,

Alexei Blue.

Comment: It's not terrible practice, in my view. Yes, it allows you to send 27 booleans instead of just one. I don't consider that a huge problem. However, an overloaded signature doesn't really cost enough to justify this.

Comment: I think it is terrible practice - if you have a second (optional) flag it needs a parameter name AND documentation. The presence of the ellipsis in the signature of the method implies an unlimited number of meaningful values can be passed to the developer using the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper term for the ellipsis is [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). Varargs allow a developer to pass a variable number of arguments.

It is not an good idea to use varargs to provide **one** optional argument. It is better to use [overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) as in the code example below.

```
public void update(Object object)
{
    update(update, false);
}

public void update(Object object, boolean check)
{
    if (check)
    {
        ...
    } //if
}
```

This way a developer is unable to pass in multiple booleans but is allowed to pass in none.

Comment: Yeah probably best to stick with the overloading functionality :) Think I'm just having one of those days lol